# Quill format all text

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, quill

I'm using Quill editor, with the following code:

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
});

quill.format('header', 'true');
```

My goal is to have ALL the text be a header (h1). However, when you return, it goes back to a paragraph.

Comment: Can you just style the text to look like headers? Why is the <h1> tag important to the application or users?

Comment: Did you manage to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. However you are using the wrong editor shortcut. In Quill and other WYSIWYG text editors pressing the return key (aka `Enter`) always closes block level element. Thus in your editor, you are experiencing something like this:

```html
<h1>I am pressing enter! H1 will close and the next line will be a new paragraph.</h1>
<p>This is my next line</p>
```

In order to insert a line break and continue inside the same block level element you must use the `Shift + Enter` shortcut instead of `Enter`. Thus your editor will see something like this:

```html
<h1> I am pressing shift + enter! The next line will be part of the same block element<br>
This is my next line</h1>
```

Comment: So I'd have to extend Quill to make it so it *always* was inside a h1?

Comment: No, you have to press `Shift + Enter` instead of `Enter` when you are jumping on a new line.

Comment: I don't want users to have to know how to do that. I was looking for a programmatic solution, where the text would always be in a h1